# Change background in Sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
Change the background of `class="col-sm-3 blog-sidebar"` into the background color that is the picture below. In other word, change the background of sidebar into the picture below

Problem:
How do you do it in relation to bootstrap v3. I tried to do it but it didn't go so well

Info:
*The webpage today (http://jsbin.com/derequjipi/edit?html,output)

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to target that element using CSS selectors.

Then style it using the background-color property:

```
.sidebar-module {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

This code should be placed within your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: I found the answer (that is ".sidebar-module") and my follow-up issue is:
How do you create the dark grey line between the background color that is white and light grey color?
Thank you!

Comment: You use the CSS border property. Here is the code with the correct border color as shown in the image you posted:

Comment: .sidebar-module { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your css:

```
.blog-sidebar{
    background-color: red; //Your color
    border: 1px solid black; //For your border as requested in comments
}
```

See [W3C Background properties](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) for more info

Comment: I found the answer (that is ".sidebar-module") and my follow-up issue is:
How do you create the dark grey line between the background color that is white and light grey color?
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!